# How to create a "cross" (or "plus") shape spinning object with Sprite Kit Physics?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Was following the example in [this Free PoBo site](http://www.free-pobo.com/build-a-simple-seesaw-with-sprite-kit-physics/), but want to create a "cross" (or "plus") shape instead of just a seesaw.

Uploaded a small test project [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8iz9650U1L2RWRrZjVyeHh0LUU/edit), basically it creates a scene as shown below, some seesaws with one of them replaced by the cross thing I tried to put in.
[image]

When you tapped on anywhere on the screen, it creates either a small ball or square box which then drops down from where you tapped. When the object hits the seesaw it spins as expected.

Problem is, the cross object doesn't always spin as expected - only when the object hits the middle green circle of the cross shape object, then it spins. Otherwise the object just drop through the blue rectangles as if it doesn't exist. Wonder what have I done wrong??!!

This is how the "cross" (or "plus") shape been added in the code. Any help appreciated, thanks!

```
....
        float wWidth = 100.0f;
        float wHeight = 10.0f;

....  

 [self addCross:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*0.75f, self.frame.size.height*0.60f)
                  game:self
             whipWidth:wWidth*0.5f
            whipHeight:wHeight];


....


-(CGMutablePathRef)getCGMutablePathRef:(float)ww thickness:(float)tt {

    CGMutablePathRef boundingPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    float halfTT = tt*0.5;

    CGPathMoveToPoint(boundingPath, NULL, halfTT, halfTT);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(boundingPath, NULL, halfTT+ww, halfTT);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(boundingPath, NULL, halfTT+ww, -halfTT);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(boundingPath, NULL, halfTT, -halfTT);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(boundingPath, NULL, halfTT, -halfTT-ww);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(boundingPath, NULL, -halfTT, -halfTT-ww);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(boundingPath, NULL, -halfTT, -halfTT);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(boundingPath, NULL, -halfTT-ww, -halfTT);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(boundingPath, NULL, -halfTT-ww, halfTT);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(boundingPath, NULL, -halfTT, halfTT);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(boundingPath, NULL, -halfTT, halfTT+ww);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(boundingPath, NULL, halfTT, halfTT+ww);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(boundingPath, NULL, halfTT, halfTT);

    return boundingPath;

}

-(void)addCross:(CGPoint)pos game:(SKScene*)game  whipWidth:(float)whipWidth whipHeight:(float)whipHeight {

    idNumber++;

    SKSpriteNode * anchor = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] size:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];
    anchor.position = pos;
    anchor.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whip_anchor-%d",idNumber];
    anchor.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:1];
    anchor.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false;
    anchor.physicsBody.dynamic = false;
    [game addChild:anchor];

    CGMutablePathRef boundingPath = [self getCGMutablePathRef:whipWidth thickness:whipHeight];

    CGMutablePathRef boundingPath2 = [self getCGMutablePathRef:whipWidth thickness:whipHeight];

    SKShapeNode* polygon = [[SKShapeNode alloc]init];

    polygon.path = CGPathCreateMutableCopy(boundingPath2);

    polygon.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:boundingPath];
    CGPathRelease(boundingPath);
    CGPathRelease(boundingPath2);

    polygon.name = @"polygon";

    polygon.lineWidth = 0.01;
    polygon.fillColor = [SKColor blueColor];
    polygon.lineWidth = 0;

    polygon.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    [anchor addChild:polygon];

    SKSpriteNode * gear = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball"];
    gear.size = CGSizeMake(whipHeight+5, whipHeight+5);
    gear.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"gear-%d",idNumber];
    [anchor addChild:gear];

    SKPhysicsJointPin* jointPin = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:anchor.physicsBody
                                                              bodyB:polygon.physicsBody
                                                             anchor:anchor.position];
    [game.physicsWorld addJoint:jointPin];


    idNumber++;

}
```

Comment: a cross is simply two overlapping rectangles

Comment: Thanks @LearnCocos2D, but if I base on the original code from "http://www.free-pobo.com/build-a-simple-seesaw-with-sprite-kit-physics/" and just add another SKSpriteNode and called it "whip2" then another SKPhysicsJointPin to join to the same "anchor", only the 2nd one get displayed. Any idea how can both rectangles be displayed? Or is there any limitation about how many SKPhysicsJointPin a SKSpriteNode can be added to? Thanks.

Comment: You can simply use a bodyWithRectangleOfSize instead of the polygon being used here.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working, instead of using polygon to draw the cross, just use a fixed joint (SKPhysicsJointFixed) to join the 2 rectangles together. Updated code posted on my blog (see section under [2014-09-03 Update]). Thanks.

http://new2objectivec.blogspot.com.au/2014/08/how-to-create-cross-or-plus-shape.html